# What is exact difference between asyncUnaryCall and futureUnaryCall in GRPC Java?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

I am unable to find a concrete difference between `futureUnaryCall` and `asyncUnaryCall` in Java gRPC client.
My understanding is they both are performance-wise same, but `futureUnaryCall` will return a `ListenableFuture` which is to be handled by the user and on the other hand, `asyncUnaryCall` expect us to pass a StreamObserver which will handle the async responses !

Please verify my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned the only difference: one uses ListenableFuture and one uses StreamObserver. It is simply two APIs to do the same thing: use the API that better fits into your application or preferences.

Comment: is there any difference in CPU utilization between the two ? Like which one to prefer for a very high RPS system ?

Comment: There's not really a performance difference; both are a thin layer on top of the ClientCall API. There's a possibility of an additional thread hop when using the ListenableFuture API, as the Future is completed on the same thread the StreamObserver callbacks occur on; if you use directExecutor for your listener you'll see same performance.